# Responsive CSS for 2k resulution screen and 4k resulution screen and 8k resolution

Tags: css, scss-mixins

I'm using 13 inch 2k and 4k resolution laptop (HP Elite Book). I need to write the css if it is 2k resolution (normal resolution) body background color make it black and if it is 4k resolution body make it red. **How to write css based on the screen resolution**. Using javascript `window.innerWidth` is same for 2k and 4k resulution (1536)

Comment: Are you trying to resize your window to try 4k or write CSS to handle 4k ?

Comment: I'm not trying to resize the screen, and writing @media.

Comment: so what are you trying to do ? You should be able to specify dedicated CSS for specific resolutions using @media)

Comment: I need to write for specific resolution

Comment: So it's about the density of the pixels? You can set a media rule for min-resolution. or use window.devicePixelRatio on javascript?

Comment: @Arno Tenkink do u have any sample code

Answer (score 1):

In you CSS file, you can specify a range of resolution to apply rules:

```
body {
    background: red;
    @media screen and (min-width: 4001px) {
        background: yellow;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 2501px) and (max-width: 4000px) {
        background: green;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 1600px) and (max-width: 2500px) {
        background: blue;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 1599px) {
        background: purple;
    }
}
```

You can find some great documentation about those on MDN website about [Using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Hello bro, don't consider screen width, why bez screen width 2k resolution screen and 4k resolution screen both are same( mine screen width 4k and 2k is 1536) so if i write above code both screen will purple color.

Answer (score 0):

Use the @media rule.

You can look at example here:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Why would this not work ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: One is 1920X1080 pixel another one is 4k is 3840 X 2160, so it won't work